# Jquery to toggle text box

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle TEXT BOX using below code but it seems to be not working. I am able to add TEXT BOX but removal is not happening.

HTML :

```
<body id="bd">
    <div id="did"></div>
    <button id="btn" >Tryit</button>
</body>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#bd").append('<input type="Text" name="fname" id="fname" />');
        $("#fname").focus();
        $("#btn").attr("id","button");
    });
    $("#button").on("click",function(){
        $("#fname").remove();
        $("#button").attr("id","btn");
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are adding elements dynamically the try using delegate() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this toggle:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").on('click',function(){

                if($("#fname").length > 0){
                    $("#fname").remove();
                }else{

                    $("#bd").append('<input type="Text" name="fname" id="fname" />');
                    $("#fname").focus();
                    $("#btn").attr("id","button");

                }

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="bd">
<div id="did"></div>
<button id="btn" >Tryit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.Its working.but i am not able to mark this as ans as I am new to this site.

Comment: @Verma an up vote would be appreciable if answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$( document ).delegate( "#btn", "click", function() {
    $("#bd").append('<input type="Text" name="fname" id="fname" />');
    $("#fname").focus();
    $("#btn").attr("id","button");
});
$( document ).delegate( "#button", "click", function() {
    $("#fname").remove();
    $("#button").attr("id","btn");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/r7card0q/)

You can use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach event for dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$("#btn").on('click',function(){
  if($("#fname").length)
     $("#fname").remove();
  else{
     $("#bd").append('<input type="Text" name="fname" id="fname" />');
     $("#fname").focus();
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating `click` event to `document` , utilizing `.replaceWith()`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var fn = function fn() {
        $("#bd").append('<input type="Text" name="fname" id="fname" />');
        $("#fname").focus();
        $(this).replaceWith($("<button id=button>Try it</button>"));
      };

      $(document).on("click", "#btn", fn);

      $(document).on("click", "#button", function() {
        $("#fname").remove();
        $(this).replaceWith($("<button id=btn>Try it</button>")).click(fn);
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="bd">
  <div id="did"></div>
  <button id="btn">Tryit</button>
</body>

</html>
```